# Which value of beta to use in common emitter amplifier circuit calculation

Tags: transistors, amplifier, common-emitter

[image: Common Emitter Amplifier]

I have this circuit. In the data sheet, I found values for the DC current gain (beta.) Which value for beta do I use in this common emitter amplifier circuit? Is my method to get the base, emitter and collector voltages correct?

1. calculated Rth by r1||r2
2. calculated Vth by r2/r1+r2 * (vcc)
3. calculated Ibq by vth-vbe / rth + (1+beta)R4
4. calculated Icq by beta * Ibq
5. calculated Ieq by (1+beta)Ibq
6. calculated Vceq by vcc - ic(r4+r3)
7. calculated emitter voltage by r4*Ieq
8. calculated collector voltage by Vceq + emitter voltage
9. Calculated base voltage by Vth - RthIbq

[image]

[image]

Comment: I assume you are calculating the quiescent condition for this circuit. If the current gain is large enough, which it is, you can get accurate enough results without using β at all. Once you know the collector current, you can calculate the upper and lower limits of the base current.

Comment: I did this circuit in a lab and want to create the circuit in software to try and get the values as close to my experimental values as possible, don't I need a value for beta to enter in the software? I am assuming that I must input 800 as beta in my calculations and the software. The aim of the task is uncertainty between measured results and expected results.

Comment: You can calculate the voltage on the base as you said. Loading by the base current is small, so you can ignore that. Subtract 0.7V to get the emitter voltage. Dividing that by emitter resistance you get the emitter current, which is almost equal to the collector current, the base current being small. From the limits of β you can now calculate the limits of the base current. Note: a quick calculation shows this circuit is very close to saturation.

Comment: If you need to use beta to calculate base resistors then use the minimum value for the amount of saturation you might encounter. That saturation level is based on how much p-p voltage your output needs to provide with your limited supply rail. Using a typical value gets you nowhere with a real design.

Comment: You do the simulation several times with a different value each time. Use min, typ and max.

Comment: Hint: To understand the main point of analyzing these circuits, try if it even matters that much if the Beta is 10, 100 or 1000. If the range is from 100 to 800 and you need to make say 1000 prototypes that operate within some tolerance you also don't know Beta or Vbe of each of the 1000 transistors you bought.

Comment: Use two values. For example, 110 and 220 if you choose the A grade and Ic is close to 2mA. Design for 110 and check the circuit still meets spec at 220. Or 110 and 800 to allow any grade of transistor.

Comment: @james Don't know why you didn't get a +1 for the question, earlier. You've written better than many do here. So I'll add mine, anyway. There are two key small signal BJT parameters that vary widely between devices and affect the DC bias point. (Obviously, your design process affects it a lot more, when done right.) These are \$\beta\$ and the saturation current (which impacts the base-emitter voltage.) You can derive quantitative sensitivity equations for the impacts of each of these on a design, which no one has yet discussed here. But most don't bother, and rather follow a process instead.

Comment: @james Ambient temperature variations are also important and significant. So a good design will "spend" some voltage overhead on the emitter's DC bias voltage. The more that is expended on it, the less the DC bias point is impacted by temperature changes. In general, you want this to be many times the thermal voltage of about 26 mV. So a half volt is perhaps a minimum, but more is better if you can afford it. The problem is that the more voltage spent there, the less that is left over for amplification. Which is why the emitter resistor may often be split and partly AC bypassed by a cap.

Comment: @james So, tell me. Are you trying to analyze a circuit you are given? For that case, you may very well want to figure out certain outcomes that may vary with BJT or temperature. Or are you trying to design a circuit based upon certain goals? In that case, you want to design so as to minimize (per certain goals) the outcomes that may vary with BJT or temperature while also achieving those overall design goals.

Answer (score 4):

> Which value for beta do I use in this common emitter amplifier circuit?

Being "completely hooked up on \$\beta\$ or \$h_{FE}\$" is a very common thing among beginners. Fact is, as you can see in the dataheet, that \$\beta\$ varies a lot. And I mean really a lot. Here it's already a factor 4 between minimum and typical. They don't even mention the highest limit.

The reason for this is that \$\beta\$ is determined by production variables that are not easy to control. So transistors are made and then measured and sorted according to their \$\beta\$, that's why there are BC107A, BC108C etc. which are mostly the same except for \$\beta\$.

*So how do circuit designers deal with this?*

We use and design for the **smallest** \$\beta\$ we can expect. And add some margin as well. So let's say we have a bunch of BC108, it's lowest (guaranteed by datasheet) \$h_{FE}\$ is 110.

From this I subtract some margin like 20% (engineers add margins to prevent ever getting stuck on an "edge"). Then I round this off to say, \$h_{FE}\$ = 90. So I would use \$h_{FE}\$ = 90 to design the circuit.

*Yes but what if \$h_{FE}\$ is much larger like \$h_{FE}\$ = 800? Then my circuit will stop working!*

Will it?
Do the excercise, design for \$h_{FE}\$ = 90.

Then, with the resistor values you got from that, re-calculate what happens when you use \$h_{FE}\$ = 800. Does that change a lot?

What happens when \$h_{FE}\$ increases is that the base current \$I_B\$ gets smaller, if we assume that the collector current \$I_C\$ stays the same.

So the NPN will draw less current from R1 and R2. In a proper design the current through R1 and R2 will be significantly (say a factor 10) higher than the **highest** \$I_B\$ we can expect.

When do we get that high \$I_B\$? When \$h_{FE}\$ is small!

So making \$h_{FE}\$ larger (800) will not change the voltage at the Base much. That means the voltage across R4 doesn't change much. What does that mean for \$I_C\$?

Answer (score 1):

A well designed BJT circuit will cope with a large range of beta, it will not depend on an exact value.

There are two 'correct values' of beta to use.

The first is infinity. It allows you to understand what the circuit is doing without getting bogged down in the mathematics.

The second is the minimum beta guaranteed over your operating range. With the BC107/8/9 transistors you've posted, you'll notice a relatively large range being specified between min and typical, and even no minimum being specified for the 'A' grade devices at 10 uA. This means if you want to build a reliable circuit operating at 10 uA, you should use 'B' grade or higher, although typically, most 'A' grade devices will work.

So how can we design for a large beta range?

Generally we design for a collector current, and the base current is what it is. To design for the minimum beta, the maximum base current, we need to make sure that our bias circuit has low enough impedance to source that current with minimal voltage drop. If removing the base current (as beta goes to infinity) causes an excessive voltage shift, then we use feedback. This can be as simple as an emitter resistor (often used in audio amplifiers), or as complicated as an external opamp setting the bias level in response to a collector current sensor (often used in RF amplifiers).